# Laravel saveMany and create relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

working on a learning project and what better to build than a todo app.

I'm using Laravel 9 and have created a new listener that hooks into the registered event of Jetstream.

This listener's role is to create some task lists with a few example tasks for new accounts.

I have this working for the task list, but can't figure out how to create a couple of tasks for each of these lists.

This is the listener currently:

```
public function handle(Registered $event)
{
    $event->user->lists()->saveMany([
        new TaskList([
            'start_date' => Carbon::today()->startOfDay()
        ]),
        new TaskList([
            'start_date' => Carbon::tomorrow()->startOfDay()
        ]),
    ]);
}
```

I could probably do something long-winded and create the task lists first, then assign some tasks then add to the user but as this is a learning project I want to see if there's a nicer way of achieving this.

It's almost like I need the methods of the factory available.